# Documenting use of attributes in C# XML docs

Tags: c#, attributes, documentation, doxygen

I have the following C# code which I am trying to document using XML comments and doxygen:

**/Controllers/FooController.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication.Attributes;
using WebApplication.Models;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ASP.NET MVC controller for /Foo/
    /// <para>
    ///     Access is limited via <see cref="ValidateThirdPartySessionAttribute"/> to the entire controller.
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    [ValidateThirdPartySession]
    public class FooController : Controller
    {
        // blah
    }
}
```

The attribute definition lives in **/Attributes/ValidateThirdPartySessionAttribute.cs** and its full name is `WebApplication.Attributes.ValidateThirdPartySessionAttribute`.

The `cref` does not link to, or pick up, the `ValidateThirdpartySessionAttribute` class when run through doxygen. I've also tried `ValidateThirdPartySession` and its full name, but nothing is recognized.

As a side node (may be relevant), I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and [MSDN claims that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) *"The compiler checks that the given code element exists"*. No warnings are ever emitted, even when I change the `cref` to gibberish.

Comment: did you try using full class name including namespace?

Comment: Yes, I've tried ValidateThirdPartySession, ValidateThirdPartySessionAttribute and WebApplication.Attributes.ValidateThirdPartySessionAttribute.